# XLOOKUP with two criteria and match_mode set to 1 behaving weird

Tags: excel, xlookup

I have two excel spreadsheets and I need to find the next largest depth from a set of samples in my first spreadsheet. I tried to achieve this using `XLOOKUP` with two criteria, and `match_mode` set to "`1`" as I don't have exact matches that I want to find.

Here is the data that I have. The middle is my output using `XLOOKUP` and different `match_mode`s.
I have marked in yellow the cells where the output is not as expected.

[image]

I used the following formulas:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; 1)
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; -1)
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; 0)
```

For example, for Sample1 at Depth 6 I would expect "7.75" as output, and not 60 when using `match_mode` set to `1`.
Sample1 at Depth 9 gives not found, but I would expect 10.85 as output when using `match_mode` set to `1`.

Any idea why excel behaves like this, as it is only in some cases that it does not behave like desired?

(Also, is there a better way to share sample data than via screenshot?)

Comment: You're comparing text strings, so the results are perfectly consistent. For example, when you concatenate 'Sample1' and '6', the result is the string 'Sample16', and the first of the concatenated strings from columns D and E which is 'greater' (i.e. alphabetically later) than this string is 'Sample160', and certainly not your expected 'Sample7.75'.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! But how can I then have two criteria in a XLOOKUP?

Comment: Many ways. You could use `FILTER`, for example `LET(ζ,FILTER(E$3:E$70,D$3:D$70=A3),XLOOKUP(B3,ζ,ζ,"Not Found",1))`